# ASP.NET Update Panel and Dynamic DOM Selection Via JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I am populating a  element with

s dynamically when the user click on checkbox.

I put both controls in updatepanel and every thing work fine.

my problem happens when trying to get the newly created elements using find() method of JQ library , sometimes I get the

s sometimes not until adding to selector a space in debug mode.

Examples:

```
$("ul li") after loading the li's into DOM , return no selection.
$("ul li ") with SPACE return the <li>s and ALSO updates the previous selector.
```

it seems to me that jquery use a cache mechanism for the selection in my situation !

Currently I am testing in chrome.

Comment: I can't confirm it uses a cache, but for sure, if you attach simple handlers to DOM elements, it does'nt take effects on elements added after the doc is loaded. If you want to attach handlers to present and future elements, you must use the `.on()` function that replace `.live()`. It will attach your handlers to present and future elements matching the selection.

Comment: Ho, I see. I suppose you have tested your selector in the chrome console ?! Is it also out of date when you call it live in the console ? Also, is your selector stored in a variable ? like `var $foo = $("...`

Comment: no I didn't use variables ..